# How to push docker image from local to azure environment?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have a docker image and I can run the docker image as a container. But I have to bind two folders local to the docker container. And I do it like this:

```
 docker run -d -p 80:80 --name cntr-apache2
```

and then I go to: localhost:80. And the app is running.

But now I want to deploy it to the azure environment.

So Logged in in the azure portal: azure login.

and in docker I logged in: docker login webadres.azurecr.io.

and then I did a push: docker push webaddres.azurecr.io/webaddress:latest.

And I got this response:

```
latest: digest: sha256:7eefd5631cbe8907afb4cb941f579a7e7786ab36f52ba7d3eeadb4524fc5dddd size: 4909
```

And I made a web app for docker.

But now if I go to the url: https://docker-webaddress.azurewebsites.net

the index is empty. And that is logical. Because I didnt bind the two directories to the docker container in azure.

So my question is:

How now to bind the two direcories with azure docker?

Thank you

And this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

# Copy virtual host into container
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# Enable rewrite mode
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install \
    libzip-dev \
    wget \
    git \
    unzip \
    -y --no-install-recommends

# Install PHP Extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_mysql

COPY ./install-composer.sh ./

COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/


EXPOSE 80

# Cleanup packages and install composer
RUN apt-get purge -y g++ \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && sh ./install-composer.sh \
    && rm ./install-composer.sh

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One option is to use App Service persistent storage.**

You need to enable the functionality first:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --settings WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE
```

Then create a mapping in a Docker Compose file even if you have a single container to deploy. The {WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} environment variable will point to /home in the App Service VM. You can use the Advanced Tools (Kudu) to create the folders and copy the needed files.

```
Wordpress:
  image: <image name:tag>
  volumes:
  - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/folder1:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
  - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/folder2:/var/www/html/ docker_webcrawler2
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-multi-container-apps)

**Another option is to mount Azure Storage.**

Note that mounts using Blobs are read-only and File Share are read-write.

Start by creating a storage account and a File Share.

Create the mount. I find that it's easier using the Portal. See how in the doc link below.

```
az storage share-rm create \
--resource-group $resourceGroupName \
--storage-account $storageAccountName \
--name $shareName \
--quota 1024 \
--enabled-protocols SMB \
--output none
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=cli&pivots=container-linux)

Comment: Your application is in a container, not deployed in /home/site/wwwroot. The mount points to /home/whatever_you_choose on the App Service instance.

Comment: Using the portal, select your Storage account, located the File share and you'll be able to see the files and upload new ones. Another option is to use the Azure Storage Explorer: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/features/storage-explorer/#overview